# Running jetty-maven-plugin in production

Tags: java, maven, jetty, production-environment, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm working on smart new web application, and I like jetty-maven-plugin that helps me in my work.

Did somebody tryied running app with jetty-maven-plugin in production environment? What are pros & cons? Are there any security or performance issues?

Comment: I think you can refer this list [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/powered/) that will give you the info where all jetty is being used as production server. I will highly recommend you this [post](http://johannesbrodwall.com/2010/03/08/why-and-how-to-use-jetty-in-mission-critical-production/) on Jetty's pros and cons as prod server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jetty-maven-plugin is a development tool and is not recommended as a production deployment mechanism.  Since you are deploying a war file then you should look to using the jetty distribution for production deployment, alternately you can look to just using jetty embedded to start up your webapp and then you are free to structure your own application in any form you like, be it a main() method or building your own start up mechanism or just using something like the maven appassembler plugin if you like.

So while there may not be any known security or performance issue related to the jetty-maven-plugin for use in production deployment, neither it nor maven itself should be viewed as a replacement for standard production deployment practices.

Comment: I'm kind of curious about the chosen answer.  It doesn't really say why.  I see this answer all the time ("it's just a dev tool"), but I never really see any reasons why it's more desirable to build something into your own application (one of the options given in the answer) versus just using the jetty-maven-plugin.  I'd like to see a concrete answer (perhaps with things like: it doesn't have an init.d script, it has XYZ security issues, etc.) Jesse, since I see you're a dev, is it just a matter of not wanting to support the plugin for that use?

Comment: In a production tool folks typically want to reduce all of the variables they can and things like dependency resolution within maven are a wildcard in many situations.  Also, the primary focus of Jetty is with embedded and distribution usage and like you say, with the maven plugin being a development tool.  One example, the classloader in play for the maven plugin is a one off that bridges the maven world with the specialized webapp classloader....not exactly what we would recommend using in production.  As for maven, it was designed to bring build and deployment conventions to management.

Comment: I think the jars in the Maven central repo should be pretty stable (and are cached locally -- and the run could even be configured to only use the local cache). I'm assuming you wouldn't move to prod without testing the versions of the jars that you've included as deps. Interesting to hear about the classloader though... thanks, that seems like a variable that might make folks nervous for prod.

Comment: ultimately maven was never intended to be a complete end to end dev to production deployment mechanism, it is a set of project management conventions that everyone can follow and make development a consistent environment.  Other systems like puppet and chef work to automate that end of app development.  I often tell people that the repository manager is the clean separation between development and operations.  One group publishes to it, the other pulls from it.